# Adding Text to PDF in memory for Downloadable file

Tags: c#, itext, memorystream, filesystemobject

**My requirements are simple-**

Add a user’s name, date and score for an exam certificate.  This would be a downloadable file for them to print.

**My Solution (So Far) –**

From searching, I have found a way to do this, which is loosely based upon this as a partial example - [How to add a PDF form field (or a text) and link in the page bottom of a page of an existing PDF document using iTextSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098665/how-to-add-a-pdf-form-field-or-a-text-and-link-in-the-page-bottom-of-a-page-of/9114340#9114340)

While my example is not exact, it is similar to that because I put a FileStream is used with a PdfWriter and Document.  I add text via a paragraph and Chunk object.  I can then write this to a Byte array that is sent with the response.

**Here’s my Issue:** 
I am restricted in our web environment by our AspNet (IIS) user which will never have Write abilities on the webserver.  I have tried substituting the FileSystem object – used for creating the PdfWriter object - with a MemoryStream.
Since a MemoryStream is non-resizable, the values are not written to file and output we hand to the response.

I will include my working and simplified version.
Call this from any C# asp.net method and along with 2 pdf files located in d:\temp.   It will drop “Joe Jones” on a template file and combine the two for one file sent with a response.

Example:

```
private void CreateCertificate()
{
    string seekerName = "Joe Jones";
    string pdf1 = "d:\\temp\\CertificateTemplateBody.pdf";
    string pdf2 = "d:\\temp\\CertificateTemplateBlank.pdf";
    float fontSize = 18;
    int fontSizeSeekerName = 45;

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf1);
    Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);

    //dynamic/source text
    // my attempt to utilize a MemoryStream in place of this have failed - nonResizable array is the issue. 
    //using (MemoryStream msOutput = new MemoryStream(GetBytesFromFile(pdf2), true))
    //{

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pdf2, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        using (Document docSource = new Document(size, 300, 100, 200, 200))
        {
            using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(docSource, fs))
            //This again would be utilizing the MemoryStream which does not work. 
            //using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(docSource, msOutput))
            {
                docSource.Open();

                PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
                Chunk myChunk = new Chunk(seekerName, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, fontSizeSeekerName, Font.NORMAL));

                float widthText = myChunk.GetWidthPoint();
                float centerPoint = (size.Width / 2);   // half mark of document
                float llx = centerPoint - (widthText / 2); // less half of text width
                float lly = widthText;
                float urx = centerPoint + (widthText / 2); // plus half of text width
                float ury = fontSize * 2;

                ct.SetSimpleColumn(new Phrase(myChunk),
                                    llx, //1llx
                                    390, //lly
                                    urx, // 530, //ury
                                    ury,//36,
                                    25,
                                    Element.ALIGN_CENTER | Element.ALIGN_TOP);
                ct.Go();

                docSource.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    //using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pdf3, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (Document doc = new Document(size))
        {

            using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
            {
                doc.Open();

                //Get page 1 of the both files then - Add the first file to coordinates 0,0
                PdfImportedPage imp1 = writer.GetImportedPage(new PdfReader(pdf1), 1);
                PdfImportedPage imp2 = writer.GetImportedPage(new PdfReader(pdf2), 1);
                writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(imp1, 0, 0);
                //Since we don't call NewPage the next call will operate on the same page
                writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(imp2, 0, 0);
                doc.Close();
            }
        }

        // - test to attach to response.
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + DateTime.Now);

        Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
        Response.End();
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Clear();
    }

}
```

**Assumption to date:**

It seems to me that within this library, there is no way to create/modify a document without the use of the fileSystem, which would need Write access.  Ideally, I would like to have a template file on the server, create a doc with the user's information added to it and combine with the Template file (opened via Read access).

I do not have the ability to have this one feature be configured with an additional app pool having a network user process that can write.  - this is my rub/dilemma.

I thank you for reading this. 
Marc

Comment: *using (MemoryStream msOutput = new MemoryStream(GetBytesFromFile(pdf2), true))* - why do you initialize this stream (which shall be written to) with bytes from some file? That been said, using memory streams with iTextSharp is a fairly standard approach.

Answer (score 1):

As @mkl said, don't bind the `MemoryStream` to anything. When you're done with a `MemoryStream` you can "export" it to a byte array. The constructor for `PdfReader` has many overloads, one of them takes a byte array so you can just pass those bytes into the `PdfReader` as if you had made a file.

I'm not going to reproduce your whole code below but this should hopefully help you.

For the first block:

```
//Create a byte array to use later
Byte[] bytes;

//using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pdf2, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
using (MemoryStream msOutput = new MemoryStream())
{
    //..PDF work here

    //Before closing the stream grab the bytes
bytes = msOutput.ToArray();
}
```

Second block:

```
PdfImportedPage imp2 = writer.GetImportedPage(new PdfReader(bytes), 1);
```